# Python Binary Search pattern from config file

Tags: python

I would like to do binary search with python. like

```
    Address = buff.find(b'\x99\x98\xB1\xFF')
```

I want to let this search pattern configurable via a JSON file. So I create a variable to keep the data from JSON file like "Pattern": "\x99\x98\xB1\xFF"

```
        Search_Pattern=Data_Structure[data]["Pattern"]
        print "Search Pattern:", Search_Pattern
        Address = buff.find(b'***Search_Pattern***') # this won't work. How to input the function variable here?
```

How could like to make the pattern from a ASCII to binary format for buff.find function?

Answer (score 0):

## Data type conversion

When `json` is read and parsed, that item will probably be read as a string, which can be converted to a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) and pass it directly to the `buff.find()` as an argument.

```
search_pattern_string = json_obj['pattern']
search_pattern_bytes = bytearray(search_pattern_string)
Address = buff.find(search_pattern_bytes)
```

Comment: thx. generally, it works with some modification.
1) remove escape character in the JASON file for Hex data 2) jason data will be Unicode. so need to convert unicode to string first. ex. Search_Pattern_ascii=Search_Pattern.encode('ascii','ignore') 3) convert data to hex format ex. Search_Pattern_hex=Search_Pattern_ascii.decode("hex");  4)  input the hex data to bytearray. ex. Search_Pattern_Binary.extend(Search_Pattern_hex)

Comment: Without seeing the whole code, it is hard to anticipate the exact encodings, variable names, and general flow before and after these lines.  Glad it worked though! If it worked, might you accept the answer? Also it is hard to read your code in the comment, could you edit your question or add an answer with the code inside a code block if that is what worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Update the solution:

JSON file:

```
{"Pattern": "9707A5FF"}
```

Partial Python Code:

```
conf_file = open(config_file)
conf = json.load(conf_file)
# get the search pattern
Search_Pattern=conf["Pattern"]
# convert unicode to ascii
Search_Pattern_ascii=Search_Pattern.encode('ascii','ignore')
#convert ascii string to hex data
Search_Pattern_hex=Search_Pattern_ascii.decode("hex")
#
Search_Pattern_Binary = bytearray()
Search_Pattern_Binary.extend(Search_Pattern_hex)

infile = open(Bin_file,'rb')
buff = infile.read()
Address = buff.find(Search_Pattern_Binary)

....
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the C++ Standard Template Library's std::vector container then use std::find.  Then you can write a Python module that calls into the C++.

Comment: Hi Michael,  thanks. I am not calling to C++. My program is just a pure Python code.

Comment: Question doesn't ask about c++, this is a python question

Comment: You have a wooden head.